# php Form fileupload problem with whitespaces in filename

Tags: php, whitespace, file-upload

I still have the problem with whitespaces:

I have an uploadform for users to upload mp3-files. It works fine, except when there are whitespaces in the filename. At the moment I tell the user not to use Filenames with whitespaces, but apparently its very common to use them in mp3s. So I would like to solve this problem. What happens is this:

**Normally:**

A user selects a file without whitespaces with an html file-input form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form2" id="form2" action="' . $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] . '">
<input type="file" style="color:#888888" name="file" id="file" />
```

Then, on the serverside I handle the file with

```
copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $newfilename);
```

This works fine.

**NOT normally:**

A user selects a file with whitespace in the filename. The print_r($_POST) looks like this:

```
Array ( [x] => 21 [y] => 32 )
```

And the print_R($_FILES) looks like this:

```
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => 11. test with spaces.mp3 [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )
```

As the tmp_name is empty, the script can't acess the file and there we have an ugly error...
So what I think I need is to manipulate the [tmp_name], so that it has no whitespaces, because my Apache/Linux Server seems to have a problem with it. Has anyone any ideas how to solve this?

Greetz and Thanks

Maenny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => 11. test with spaces.mp3 [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )`

error code 1 means The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. Maybe here is your problem.

Comment: Man I feel stupid now - I had the POST_max_size right but the max_upload_size not. Could you tell me where you found the errorcode-definitions? thx

Comment: You can find definitions on php.net website: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest not to use the real filename because if at any time you want to scale up you are going to have a lot of troubles, if you want to keep the original filename use an extra field for that. ;)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: My fault, I didn't mention it - of yourse I rename the filename - thing is, when I have an $_FILES[tmp_name] that is empty because of the server not handling whitespaces, I can't even rename anything, let alone copy.

Comment: it only happens with mp3 files with white spaces or with any file with whitespace? (have you checked what aurismasL said about the size?)